# Bread machine yeast substitute active to quick rise

Tags: yeast

Bread machine calls for active dry yeast. I have quick rise yeast can I still use it.The recipe calls for 1/4 cup water.Do I need to add the water to the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the type of dry yeast used shouldn't change the amount of water you need. However, it will probably change the timing, so you'll want to keep an eye on the bread machine and adjust its rise times as needed.

(And keep track of the new times, so you can re-use them if you make the same recipe again).